# if statement cannot find string when match() method applied to it

Tags: javascript, regex

Need to perform simple operation. If fileExt is not .jpg .jpeg .png .pdf, alert should be displayed.

```
var fileName = 'upload-success.png';
var fileExt = fileName.match(/\.[a-z]{3,4}$/i); // fails
// var fileExt = '.png'; // works

if (fileExt !== ".jpg" && fileExt !== ".jpeg" && fileExt !== ".png" && fileExt !== ".pdf") {
    alert('Incorrect Extension: '+fileExt);
}
```

In both cases of setting fileExt result is the same.
But in case of using match - if statement cannot find string.

http://jsfiddle.net/mCjSW/1/

Comment: Hey Danilo, bring this != solution back. I will accept it. =))

Comment: Weak comparison will work here as JS has some pretty weird type coercion rules. It will work in this case, but I guess it's better to stay away from "that part of town" if you need reliable code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about directly using [`match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to check the file extension?

```
var f = 'foo.png';

if (!f.match(/\.(jpe?g|png|pdf)$/))
    alert('invalid extension');
```

Due to he fact that we don't need the returned array by `match()`, we could just use [`test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) here:

```
if (!/\.(jpe?g|png|pdf)$/.test(f))
    alert('invalid extension');
```

Remember that looking at a file's extension does not ensure that its content matches the extension's file type; however, filtering extensions ensures that wrong files aren't *accidentally* chosen/uploaded by the user. Looking at the file's MIME-type is definitely advisable, but such a check must be done server-side (there are a lot of ways to bypass the checks done with javascript of course, most obvious would be deactivating javascript support in the browser).

Comment: MIME checks are going through PHP script. Congrats with your 1000 points of reputation.

Comment: You shouldn't use `match` for that, but `/\.(jpe?g|png|pdf)$/.test(fileName)`

Comment: @watain: BTW, what's the point of MIME checking using JavaScript if it's all getting processed inside client's browser (which can be fooled around)?

Comment: @Radio: yes, it wouldn't make sense to check the MIME on the client. What I actually meant (sorry for not being clear enough) was to check it server-side, but as you already mentioned your PHP script takes care of that. Checking the extension on the client is totally OK, since you want to make sure the client doesn't choose wrong files by accident. I will adjust my answer to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

`.match()` returns an Array so you'll have to use:

```
var fileExt = fileName.match(/\.[a-z]{3,4}$/i)[0];
```

**[MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)**

Comment: Can you explain why in alert (without [0]), - I'm not getting array() or object() ??

Comment: You can alert Arrays and will get their values, try `alert(['hello','world']);`